# Enterprise Library, Exception Handling Block: Can't use custom exceptions for wrapping in a WrapHandler

Tags: c#, .net, exception, enterprise-library

I want to use the Enterprise Library Exception Handling Block for exception handling.
To try it I wrote a simple app that throws and processes exceptions and while playing with it I encountered the following:

When I use a BCL exception like `System.ApplicationException`, thrown exceptions are wrapped as they should:

Policy:

```
<exceptionPolicies>
    <add name="DalPolicy">
        <exceptionTypes>
            <add name="DbPrimitiveHandledException" type="Exceptions.DbPrimitiveHandledException, Exceptions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
                postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
                <exceptionHandlers>
                    <add name="DAL Wrap Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WrapHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                        exceptionMessage="Dal Wrapper Exception" wrapExceptionType="System.ApplicationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
                </exceptionHandlers>
            </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
    </add>
    ...
</exceptionPolicies>
```

Console output:

> System.ApplicationException: Dal Wrapper Exception --->
>   Exceptions.DbPrimitiveHandledException: Db Handled Policed exception...

But when I try to use my own exception:

```
public class DalWrapperException : Exception
{
    public DalWrapperException()
    { }

    public DalWrapperException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }
}
```

Policy:

```
<exceptionPolicies>
    <add name="DalPolicy">
        <exceptionTypes>
            <add name="DbPrimitiveHandledException" type="Exceptions.DbPrimitiveHandledException, Exceptions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
                postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
                <exceptionHandlers>
                    <add name="DAL Wrap Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WrapHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                        exceptionMessage="Dal Wrapper Exception" wrapExceptionType="Exceptions.DalWrapperException, Exceptions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                </exceptionHandlers>
            </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
    </add>
    ...
</exceptionPolicies>
```

Wrapping doesn't work - I'm getting an ExceptionHandlingException:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlingException: Unable to handle exception: 'WrapHandler'.
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my exception or configuration?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the exception class. It must implement one more constructor that accepts an inner exception:

```
public class DalWrapperException : Exception
{
    public DalWrapperException()
    { }

    public DalWrapperException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }

    public DalWrapperException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Tuzo, thank you for reminding, but according to the rules of StackOverflow I can't mark my own answer as accepted in two days.